# QSharedMemory unable to make key

Tags: shared-memory

I am newbie to Qt and I want to use QSharedMemory as facility to connect some applications together during runtime.
I have checked out the QSharedMemory example and extracted everything I need to use it.

The problem here is that the QSharedMemory instance fails to allocate memory.
When I call `create()` it returns false,
and when I print the error message stored in `errorString()`, it shows the error below:

`QSharedMemory::create: unable to make key`

My piece of code is similar to this:

```
QSharedMemory sharedmemory;
if(sharedmemory.isAttached())
    sharedmemory.detach();

QString st = "this is the shared data";
QBuffer buffer;
buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);
QDataStream out(&buffer);
out << st;
int size = buffer.size();

if(!sharedmemory.create(size))
{
    std::cout<<sharedmemory.errorString().toStdString()<<std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

No matter what I give as `size` to the `create()` method, it just doesn't allocate memory.

Any idea is appriciated.
Thanks
Mahdi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code of `qsharedmemory_unix.cpp`:

```cpp
// build file if needed
int built = createUnixKeyFile(nativeKey);
if (built == -1) {
    errorString = QSharedMemory::tr("%1: unable to make key").arg(QLatin1String("QSharedMemory::create"));
    error = QSharedMemory::KeyError;
    return false;
}
```

From the Qt documentation for `QSharedMemory`:

> `QSharedMemory::QSharedMemory ( const QString & key, QObject * parent = 0 )`
>
> Constructs a shared memory object with the given parent and with its key set to key. Because its key is set, its `create()` and `attach()` functions can be called.
>
> See also `setKey()`, `create()`, and `attach()`.
>
> ---
>
> `QSharedMemory::QSharedMemory ( QObject * parent = 0 )`
>
> This function overloads `QSharedMemory()`.
>
> Constructs a shared memory object with the given parent. The shared memory object's key is not set by the constructor, so the shared memory object does not have an underlying shared memory segment attached. *The key must be set with `setKey()` before `create()` or `attach()` can be used.*
>
> See also `setKey()`.

(emphasis mine)

You are basically using the second form of the constructor and not setting the shared memory key. You should give `QSharedMemory` a key name - consult [shm_open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/shm_open.html) for information on what this key can be. Note that in Linux POSIX shared memory is implemented as a filesystem in `/dev/shm` and there are certain restrictions on the key name - it cannot contain forward slashes (`/`) anywhere except at the beginning of the name since having such would require directories to be created in `/dev/shm` and both `shm_open()` and `QSharedMemory::createUnixKeyFile()` are less than willing to do so.